# I can't find module "core" in perl dir on ubuntu 18.x

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, perl, nginx

I'm trying compile nginx ... configure seems ok, then when I type make I get following error:

```
make
make -f objs/Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/paul/src/ngxbuild/nginx-1.14.0'
cc -o objs/ngx_http_perl_module.so \
objs/src/http/modules/perl/ngx_http_perl_module.o \
objs/ngx_http_perl_module_modules.o \
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC -Wl,-E -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lc -lcrypt \
-shared
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lperl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
objs/Makefile:1670: recipe for target 'objs/ngx_http_perl_module.so' failed
make[1]: *** [objs/ngx_http_perl_module.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/paul/src/ngxbuild/nginx-1.14.0'
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

so error is **cannot find -lperl**

well the problem seems that in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26/` there's no `CORE` directory.
I use Ubuntu server 18.0, update and upgraded, an I can't find the way to update...

Debian stretch contain perl 5.24.1 and CORE directory exist in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24/`, so why ubuntu won't install core directory and how install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Can not find -lperl` error means it can not find `libperl`.

On Debian Stretch this is provided by `libperl-dev`

```
% apt-file list libperl-dev
libperl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.a
libperl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so
libperl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libperl-dev/README.cross
libperl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libperl-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
libperl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libperl-dev/copyright
```

I would expect a similar package to be needed on Ubuntu.

Comment: yes apt install libperl-dev solve errors, @ S.Harris about -lperl error  look at the line "/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lperl" it's the 7 starting from the buttom

Comment: The command option `-lperl` means "link in the perl library".  The error message says it couldn't find the relevant `libperl` file.